# Problem with drawing rectangles on some numbers in turtle python

Tags: python, python-turtle

When I draw a rectangles with a width of 31.25, I get on one crooked line, but it works only if this value ends at .25 or .75, In other numbers this code draws well, also if I open it in fullscreen it restores to normal. Maybe this problem with rendering in turtle or my very stupid error, but I can't find something about it, but it's so strange. I can add the minimal number to the side and I won't see it, but it isn't the best way.

[image: image that demonstarate the problem]

I wrote a part of the code to demonstrate this problem.

```
import turtle

def square(t: turtle.Turtle, side, color):
    t.fillcolor("red")
    t.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        t.forward(side)
        t.right(90)
    t.end_fill()

def main():
    t = turtle.Turtle()

    t.left(90)

    side = 31.25

    for _ in range(4):
        square(t, side, "red")
        t.forward(side)
    
    turtle.done()

main()
```

Thank you.

I expect from my drawing I will get exact rectangles. I fixed it and added a very small number. Also if I open it in fullscreen it goes into a normal needed state

Comment: You can't draw 1/4 of a pixel so I would guess some rounding has to occur when you move a fractional distance and the Turtle software converts that distance to pixels.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Hello. Yes you are right. But interesting that turtle reacts to this situation in different ways. Some lines turtle draws normal, another drawed badly.